# Controller method not found in laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hello I am running into a problem with two routes/controllers in Laravel 4.1

I am getting the missing method error every time but I think everything is good ( as I checked )

Here are the results [image]

The routes

```
# Review Management
Route::post('reviews/{review}/approved', 'AdminReviewsController@postApproved')
->where('review', '[0-9]+');
Route::post('reviews/{review}/disapproved', 'AdminReviewsController@postDisapproved')
->where('review', '[0-9]+');
Route::controller('reviews', 'AdminReviewsController');
```

And this is the methods themselves.

```
    public function postApproved($review) {

    Review::where('id', '=', $review)->update(array('approved' => 1));

    Redirect::back()->with('notice', 'Review accepted');
}

public function postDisapproved($review) {

    Review::where('id', '=', $review)->update(array('approved' => 0));

    Redirect::back()->with('notice', 'Review denied');
}
```

I don't know what the problem is I even tried composer dump-autoload like 20times but no succes. so How do I solve this?

Comment: Is that all of your routes listed from `artisan routes`? If the route shows, there is a chance you have a conflicting controller that doesn't contain that method.

Comment: This is all the routes. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yPKKWnkE I don't know if there is another controller conflicting but im not very experienced with laravel so I might have overlooked something

Comment: You have route groups, right? I'm afraid you'll have to show them all, because the problem looks like to be in another piece of code.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro Yes I have groups. Here you go the full list of my routes. http://pastebin.com/jVVBHW8d

Comment: This is how your routes are being generated here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bddhX8rt (i just changed all controllers names to HomeController). Approved and disaproved are not blank. What is generating those other filters (admin_b1b79d, manage_comments_152828)? That might be the source of your glitch.

Comment: As I am using Zizacos' entrust package I do this in my filters.php http://pastebin.com/pv1y4Lhx

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro I found out that when the request is made it is a GET request instead of a post request. because the use of data tables ( jQuery plugin for Laravel ) so therefore changing the controllers to any made it! thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Reshad or you add `serverMethod : "POST"` to the dataTables initialisation options.

Comment: @DavidBarker i tried that but somehow it didnt work. Any solved the problem as it should work.

Answer (score 0):

try putting `route::controller()` before the other two

Comment: That was not the problem the routes were just ok it was just that the datatables plugin sent a get method instead of post so changing the route to any solved the problem